# SharePoint: Customize default NewForm.aspx and hide some fields according to given permissions

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My requirement is to restrict users to view/add/edit fields of a list as per their given group/permission. To achieve this objective as per my understanding I have to generate custom list forms. If anyone can help me to customize NewFrom.Aspx and code in such a way that we can check current user group/permission and hide fields which should not be accessible to him.

I have derived solution after googling and have thought to apply below thing after creating new custom list form. I want to know if this approach is good enough or give any optimal solution to it.

```
        var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        web.Update();
        var lists = web.Lists["SomeList"];
        var f = lists.Fields["SomeField"];
        if(){ //to check if user is in role
        f.ShowInEditForm = false;
        f.ShowInNewForm = false;
        f.Update();
        }
```

The same list will be used ac cross all the users so I think above solution might not be optimal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As **SharePoint does not support Column level permissions**, there are some third party tools available for column level permissions:

- [Column Level Security](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx)
- [SharePoint Column/View Permission](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission-business-scenario.html#CVP-1)

**For Custom NewForm**:

- You can develop the custom webpart for NewForm where you can display fields as per the permissions.
- Then set this webpart in place of default NewForm.aspx, so when ever user click on *NewItem* link of the list then rather than default sharepoint form it will open custom webpart.
- You can replace the default NewForm webpart with custom webpart with following code:

  ```
    
  public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
          {
              SPWeb currentWeb = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
              try
              {
              SPLimitedWebPartManager NewForm = currentWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Lists/listname1/NewForm.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
              AddWebPart(NewForm);
              }
              catch (Exception)
              {
                  throw;
              }
            }
  protected void AddWebPart(SPLimitedWebPartManager MainPage)
      {
          MainPage.WebParts[0].Hidden = true;
          MainPage.SaveChanges(MainPage.WebParts[0]);
          try
          {
              var linqqry = from wp in MainPage.WebParts.Cast()
                            where wp.GetType() == typeof(Webpart1.Webpart1)
                            select wp;

          if (linqqry.Count() == 0)
          {
              //Create an instance of WPMenu Webpart and add in a Webpart zone
              Webpart1.Webpart1 wpWebPart = new Webpart1.Webpart1();
              MainPage.AddWebPart(wpWebPart, "Main", 0);
              MainPage.SaveChanges(wpWebPart);
          }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
          }
  }
  ```